# How to explore an array step-by-step in a Controller based on user input in the View?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

All,

I am building a small website using WAMPserver.  My site follows an MVC pattern.  At one point I generate an array of strings on the controller side.  I want to display each array element to the user, and only show the next item once the user clicks on a button on the view.

I need to capture the info of those clicks at each step and therefore I don't want to send the entire array to the browser - plus it could slow things too much.

How do I accomplish that?  If I put the array through a `foreach` loop on the controller side, I only send to the view the last element.  If I try to control the `foreach` with a boolean whose value change inside the `foreach`, I have no idea how to change the value of the boolean based on the user's action.

Intuitively I suppose this will require an Ajax call but I have little experience with Ajax and all of it as been to pull data from the server.

Alternatively, should I try to associate a Javascript `submit()` function to a button click event and use that to change a `$_POST` variable (e.g., as a boolean that I would then change back inside the `foreach` on the server)?

Or am I thinking about that the wrong way?

Comment: Cant you use the ids of the items in the array?

Comment: You know you should really try out one of your ideas and see how it goes. Then post the code and see how we can help. Someone will answer now but there is a lot to learn trying out stuff yourself.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses - Let's make sure I understand. Are you saying that I should just send the size of the array, and then use a `for` loop in Javascript / Ajax to pull each element?

Comment: What exactly is your programming problem?

Comment: @JDelage no, each item in an array got an Id and you can call a certain item with his Id and you want to return 1 element of an array, so you can just use `$array[$id]`

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array with multiple items, and you want the user to read through them one at a time while tracking their clicks?

Not sure what framework your using, but most controllers methods allow you to take paramaters. So the controller would look something like this:

```
class ItemController {
    public function view($id = 0) {
        DB::increment('counter to increment');
        $array = DB::get('db query here or something');
        View::render($array[$id]);
    }
}
```

And then the user would access `domain.com/item/view/0`, `domain.com/item/view/1`, `domain.com/item/view/2` sequentially. (You would provide the links via pagination)

What's happening, is that your router will route the `request` of `domain.com/item/0` to `domain.com/{controller}/{method}/{id}`, so effectively they go to the same controller but render the view differently depending on the *parameter* given.

**edit**: forgot to put the method in the URI's

No need for JS, hope that helps.